# How to show that $g$ attains maximum at $0$ or $1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous，define

$$g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},\quad g(x):=\int_0^1|f(t)-x|dt$$

Show that $g$ attains maximum at $0$ or $1$.

I don't know how to approach, any hints?

Comment: It looks like $g$ is a function of $x$ and that you are asking that we prove for any $f(t)$ that $g$ does not attain a maximum.  If $f(t) \gt 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, then $g(x)$ attains a maximum at $x=0$.  Please review your question.

Comment: @RossMillikan But $0\notin (0,1)$.

Comment: @Coiacy I have edit the post

Comment: You can prove the stronger statement that $g$ does not attain its maximum on $(0,1)$.  To prove that it attains its maximum at $0$ or $1$ does not require that $f$ be continuous, merely that it is integrable.

Comment: If $f(t) \ge 1$ for all $t$, then $g(x)$ is linear with slope $-1$.  It is not constant.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith Right, sorry about my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially we need to use convexity of g(x). For any $x,t\in(0,1)$, we have 
$$
|f(t)-x|\le x|f(t)-1|+(1-x)|f(t)|
$$

Integrate on both sides form $0$ to $1$ with respect to $t$, we obtain

$$
g(x)\le x\cdot g(1)+(1-x)\cdot g(0)
$$.

Now suppose the contrary, if there exists $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $g(x_0)>g(0)$ and $g(x_0)>g(1)$, then

$$
 x_0\cdot g(1)+(1-x_0)\cdot g(0)<g(x_0)\le x_0\cdot g(1)+(1-x_0)\cdot g(0)
$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $g$ is convex.  This follows since $x \mapsto |x-c|$ is convex.

Now to show is that $g$ is non-constant.  There are two possibilities.

1. Either $f([0,1]) \subset (-\infty, 0]$, or $f([0,1]) \subset [1,\infty)$.  And in either of these cases, $g$ is linear with slope $-1$ or $1$.
2. Or, since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\epsilon,\delta>0$, $t_0\in (\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$ such that $f([t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon]) \subset [\delta,1-\delta]$.  Then for $t \in [t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon]$ we have that $$\tfrac12|f(t)| + \tfrac12|f(t)-1| = \tfrac12 f(t) + \tfrac12(1-f(t)) = \tfrac12 \ge |f(t)-\tfrac12| + \delta $$
   Since for all $t \in [0,1]$ we also have
   $$\tfrac12|f(t)| + \tfrac12|f(t)-1|  \ge |f(t)-\tfrac12|  $$
   then integrating we get
   $$ \tfrac12 g(0) + \tfrac12 g(1) \ge g(\tfrac12) + 2\epsilon\delta ,$$
   and hence $g$ is non-constant.

Since $g$ is convex and non-constant, it cannot attain its maximum on $(0,1)$.

Comment: good idea! I just simplified a bit in the following.

Comment: If $g$ is constant, it still reaches its maximum at $0$ or (and, actually)  $1$. But the question was edited... I guess you answered an earlier version.

Comment: @julien I always dealt with the non-constant issue.  It is Coiacy's answer that didn't deal with the non-constant case.

Comment: I see: I'll just add for people who've only seen the new version  that the initial question was to show that $g$ does no reach its maximum on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @julien But to prove that $g$ attains its maximum at $0$ or $1$ does not require $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: Indeed, your answer is very nice, and the original question was more interesting. I was just pointing out that it might get the reader confused now that the question has been edited.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  I was out of the loop for several hours.